# Case analysis in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

How do I apply case analysis in Isabelle? I was looking for something similar to `apply (induct x)` (which is used for induction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case analysis is usually performed with the `cases` method (also see "cases (method)" in the index of the [Isabelle/Isar Reference manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2014/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/isar-ref.pdf) of Isabelle2014). If you are a beginner, I recommend the tutorial [Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2014/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/prog-prove.pdf).

Note that since Isabelle 2014, the documentation is also available in the Isabelle/jEdit IDE in the Documentation panel.

Comment: Both `proof` and `apply` take arbitrary proof methods. However, `proof` starts a structured proof; while `apply` can be used to make (unstructured) proof scripts. If you are new to Isabelle, I would really suggest you make yourself familiar with the structured proof style. In particular case distinctions and inductions get messy very fast in unstructured proofs.